# Builtin functions and values being tagged as undefined

Tags: pydev

False, isinstance, list, int, setattr, range, and many others are being tagged as undefined.  I"m running Aptana Studio 3 version 3.2.

I have run both of the interpreter updates:
 - Window / Preferences / Interpreter - Python / Apply
 - Properties / PyDev - PYTHONPATH / Apply
cleared error markers, etc.  Nothing seems to work.

...Thanks,
...Ken

I am curious as to what happened, but my patience gave way to irritation, so I re-installed from scratch and all is well.  I'm guessing the latest update from Aptana ate something that disagreed with it, but it's hard to tell.  I did save the previous install in case someone has an idea for me to test.

Comment: please explain what the problem is, and how you encounter this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that PyDev was not able to create a shell/sockets to the shell (usually meaning you either have some firewall enabled blocking the communication or you have a misconfiguration in your pythonpath).

So, it'd be nice if you could share if you have something in your error log in that old installation -- but if it's all working on your new, I'm not sure it's worth the time :)

Also related: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhenIdoacodecompletion%2CPyDevhangs%2CwhatcanIdo%3F

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and switched to pycharm. It's wonderful!